# Bulma Column Responsiveness in Mobile

Tags: bulma

By default, the below code is good but I have few problems

- How to make 3 columns in mobile view per row and 1 row with 6 columns in desktop.
- Tablet view is good as it's showing 2 columns per row.

While searching for the code I find in bootstrap it's more easy to do than in Bulma.

Here is the full code I am currently doing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">

                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fourth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: using bootstrap col classes is not an option?

Comment: Nope, it's Bulma

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to replace "is-one-fourth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen" by "is-2-desktop" and "is-one-fifth-desktop is-one-fifth-widescreen" also by "is-2-desktop".
As Bulma has 12 spaces for columns. If you set the size for desktop (and up) there will be 6 items if you give them size 2.

In this example is-multiline is also important. Otherwise the last columns will disappear.

Regards Paul.
Below the working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

    <title>2-3-6 example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">

                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop is-2-widescreen">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-half-mobile is-one-third-tablet is-2-desktop">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-square">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```